# Как отправить сообщение пост-запросом в определенный канал?

Tags: javascript, discord

Как сделать, чтобы запрос отправлял сообщение в определенный канал?

```js
async function StartButton() {
    var discordToken    = document.getElementById('discordToken').value;
    var channelID       = document.getElementById('channelID').value;
    var message         = document.getElementById('message').value;
    var delaySecs       = document.getElementById('delaySecs').value;


    var imageOne        = document.getElementById('imageOne').value;
    var imageTwo        = document.getElementById('imageTwo').value;
    var imageThree      = document.getElementById('imageThree').value;

    //https://discordapp.com/api/v9/channels/channelid/messages
    
    let response = await fetch(`https://discordapp.com/api/v9/channels/${channelID}/messages`, {
        headers: {
            'authorization': discordToken, 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    });

    if (response.ok) { // если HTTP-статус в диапазоне 200-299
      // получаем тело ответа (см. про этот метод ниже)
      alert("maybe?");
    } else {
      alert("Ошибка HTTP: " + response.status);
    }

}
```

Comment: не надо дублировать вопросы. Достаточно отредактировать исходный вопрос, добавив в него необходимую информацию